# When should a bolt and hole be tapped at an angle, if ever, from a structural/strength standpoint?

Tags: structural-analysis, 3d-printing, bolting

Assuming the head of a bolt makes proper contact with its surface and clamps properly, and tapping an angled hole is not an issue, when would an angled bolt and hole (relative to the primary surface) be preferred?

This is a question I've held for quite a while out of curiosity, due to inexperience with its techniques and uses. I've searched a lot, but I may not know the proper wordage for "angled bolt holes", as even google gives me relatively few relevant results. the words "bolt, pitch, drill" and "angle" give more definitions and "how to"s than "when to"s.

but when would they be preferred from a structural or maintenance standpoint? I believe it doesn't provide as much clamping force. Are they simply always suboptimal, or are there common cases where it would be preferred, but is not worth the work to machine such geometries? The bolt does pass through much more material in a shorter vertical length, and more of the bolt's cross section lays along the faying surface, but I'm not totally sure what effects those would have.

[image]

I mostly use additive manufacturing to produce the parts, needing only to have the holes tapped, which greatly simplifies the creation of these holes, but I've only ever used it to slim down a surface or keep an exposed panel smooth, and I noticed that I had followed my gut and avoided angling the bolts to the immediate surfaces they were connecting, rather than the main surface, which I could simply have turned over and drilled through for a flush fit. In my case it didn't matter much- I just needed a sensor shielded, but the fact I had made such a decision without thinking intrigued me later as I inspected the finished part. (and confirmed "aesthetics" is a valid use for it, at the very least)

[image][image]

Comment: the purpose of the bolt is to pull the surfaces together so that the friction between the surface carries the load sideways. But obviously there is no wrong way to use hardware i have structural contacts where the screw puches outwards so that the closing of it frees the structure.

Comment: What is your understanding of "clamps properly"? This can be clamped loosely, can be free to rotate or can be solidly fixed. All these an be "clamped properly".

Comment: I mostly work with larger stuff, so getting the bolts started is an issue. In your second image, using parallels bolts is good if the pieces are very rigid. But I'm using a 12 pound sledgehammer to align the plates and holes. Off-angle bolts either wont start or will put cracking stresses on the hole when torqued.